# Strange output of a Mathematica function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Hi I am unable to understand the output of the following function.

```
ListPointPlot3D[Table[Sin[x^2 + y],
                      {x, 0, 3, 0.15}, {y, 0, 3, 0.15}],
                      AxesLabel -> {"X axis", "Y axis", "Z axis"}
               ]
```

[image]

I have told X and Y to be in the interval `[0,3]` But the diagram is showing an entirely different range for these variables from  about `[0,21]`.

How did this happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You gave `ListPointPlot3D` a matrix of values.  Each value of interpreted as a "height" (z-coordinate) and the matrix indices of the values as the x and y coordinates.

Perhaps you want

```
ListPointPlot3D[Join @@ Table[{x, y, Sin[x^2 + y]}, {x, 0, 3, 0.15}, {y, 0, 3, 0.15}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or

```
Plot3D[Sin[x^2 + y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Also take a look at the docs of the `Mesh` option of `Plot3D`.

Comment: The first of your suggestions seems to be working though. Let me just tinker around with it briefly before accepting your answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `DataRange` option to specify the scope of the axes:

```
ListPointPlot3D[Table[Sin[x^2 + y], {y, 0, 3, 0.15}, {x, 0, 3, 0.15}],
   AxesLabel -> {"X axis", "Y axis", "Z axis"}, 
   DataRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 3}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that I also switched the `x` and `y` iterators in the `Table`, because `Table[..., {x, ..}, {y, ...}]` corresponds to `Table[Table[..., {y, ...}], {x, ...}]`.  (You can see this is correct by changing one of the `0.15` step sizes to `1`.)

Answer (score 4):

All the 2D `List*` plotting functions take a `List` like `{{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...}` as their first argument and this will plot the `x` and `y` points correctly. However, if you provide only one set of coordinates as `{y1,y2,...}`, then it uses the position of each of those `y_i`s for the x ticks. Similarly for all the `List*3D` plotting functions.

So in your case, there is only one variable, the `z` variable and it just uses the index of the individual sub`List`s for the `x` and `y` ticks. Try this instead:

```
ListPointPlot3D[
 Flatten[Table[{x, y, Sin[x^2 + y]}, {x, 0, 3, 0.15}, {y, 0, 3, 
    0.15}], 1], AxesLabel -> {"X axis", "Y axis", "Z axis"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

it appears to be each 'sample' not the actual x/y value as there are 20 0.15's between 0 and 3 and this is the step size of your table